# Creating jenkins pipeline in a shared library script outside of call() function?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline in a shared library, found in the following file:

```
vars/my_pipeline.groovy
```

The contents of *vars/my_pipeline.groovy* is:

```
def call() {
  pipeline {
    agent { label 'linux' }
    stages {
      stage('Run') {
        steps {
          echo "Hello!"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
return this
```

In the jenkins script I can call this as follows:

```
@Library('jenkins-my-lib') _

my_pipeline()
```

And everything works as expected: the *vars/my_pipeline.groovy* script is loaded, and the *call()* function is invoked, and the pipeline runs.

Next I moved the *pipeline{...}* call to another function:

```
def call() {
  call_my_pipeline()
}

def call_my_pipeline() {
  pipeline {
    agent { label 'linux' }
    stages {
      stage('Run') {
        steps {
          echo "Hello!"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
return this
```

I expected that *my_pipeline()* would invoke the *call()* function, which would invoke the *call_my_pipeline()* function, which contains the *pipeline{...}* DSL.

Instead I get an error:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'stages' found among steps [...]
```

So the *pipeline{...}* call starts, but can't find the *stages{...}* method in the DSL.

**Edit**

I also get the same error when I invoke the *call()* method explicitly:

```
@Library('jenkins-my-lib') _

my_pipeline.call()
```

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to create a *pipeline{...}* in a function that is not *call()* in a jenkins shared library *vars/* script?

Comment: If you want to define a pipeline in a global variable method instead of a custom step then it requires importing the pipeline library (this may already be occurring implicitly) and using Groovy syntax. It is not normal usage to define an entire pipeline in a global var method, but you can see a usage example for a smaller scope at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps.